# Timer and multi threading in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, timer

I am using the System.Times.Timer for monitoring a process and this will invoke a method regularly. But I am facing an issue that the invocation is done using multithreading. If I remove the timer, then it will work as STA. WIth Timer,When I call the ElapsedMethod to invoke another function, then it is changing to MTA, which causes exception for me at the end.

Comment: what is the exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the `System.Timers.Timer` to `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` and all the action will be performed on the UI thread.

if you don't wanna do that then you can set the `SynchronizingObject` to `this`. because When SynchronizingObject is null, the method that handles the Elapsed event is called on a thread from the system-thread pool

Comment: That's `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`

Answer (score 2):

`System.Timers.Timer` has a [SynchronizingObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.synchronizingobject.aspx) property that you can set to have the event be marshaled to the UI thread. Set that to the Form. That is:

```
System.Timers.Timer Timer1 = new System.Timers.Timer();
Timer1.SynchronizingObject = this;
// add other Timer initialization here
```